# Force android to use 3G while Wifi is enabled or wait for response from Gmail

Tags: android, gmail, wifi, 3g, notify

I made an app wich will run onto a local Wifi (not internet connection) and it need to send mail via Gmail or maybe the Email app. So I would like to force it through 3G connection. I've done this :

```
if (imageLoaded) {

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {

    }else{
        if (ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
                || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX) {
            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            if (wm != null)
                System.out.println(wm.disconnect());
        }
        while (true) {
            ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (ni != null && ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
                        && ni.isConnected()) {
                sendOnClick();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the sending is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, adress);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);               

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);      

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "mail"));
}
```

But the thing is I have no clue how to be notified whan the mail is sent so I can reconnect to my local Wifi. Any idea on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you simply need to use the startActivityForResult method to launch your mail activity.

You will then be warned in the onActivityResult callback of your activity when the Email application goes back to your app.

See : [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Starting :

```
private final static int INTENT_UUID = 69;//Declare this in your class
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "mail"), INTENT_UUID);
```

Receiving afterwards :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == INTENT_UUID) {
    //Do something
  }     
}
```

Comment: I want to send an email through 3G as the Wifi connection is only local so it can't be connected on internet. (Btw what does itikbird means?)

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I didn't understand the first part of your question. Please clarify how you send the mail. Maybe ad the code that sends the email.

Comment: I clarified this. I send with a third party client. (i.e. Gmail or Email app)

Comment: I don't see the update on your post with the code you use to send the email.

Comment: Ok here it is. I thought saying that I send it through gmail was enough for you.